# How to make multiple IN ["V1", "V3","V5"] query

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

For a documents of that has the following structure

```
{
  "countryCode": "US",
  "status" : "Pending"
}
```

where the `countryCode` has limited list of options (ISO country codes)
and the `status` has a limited set of options too I need to select only the documents that
are for the given list of countries basically and given list of statuses

in SQL means it would be something like

`countryCode IN ["US","AR", "UK"]` *AND* `status IN ["Pending", "Error", "Loading"]`

is it at all possible in Cloudant / CouchDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CouchDB's [`/db/_find`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html), the following [`selector`](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#find-selectors) produces the desired result:

```
{
   "selector":{
      "$and":[
         {
            "countryCode":{
               "$in":["US", "AR", "UK"]
            }
         },
         {
            "status":{
               "$in":["Pending", "Error", "Loading"]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

> [Condition operators](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#condition-operators) such as `$in` are specific to a field, and are used to evaluate the value stored in that field.

**CURL**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:5984/<db>/_find -d '{"selector":{"$and":[{"countryCode":{"$in":["US", "AR", "UK"]}},{"status":{"$in":["Pending", "Error", "Loading"]}}]}}'
```